# What is the fastest way to solve a large-scale quadratic programming problem with inequality constraint?

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve problem as follows:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  &\mathop{min} \limits_{\textbf{x}_1...\textbf{x}_k} \  \frac{1}{2}\textbf{x}_1^T\textbf{Q}_1\textbf{x}_1+\textbf{q}_1^T\textbf{x}_1+...+\frac{1}{2}\textbf{x}_k^T\textbf{Q}_k\textbf{x}_k+\textbf{q}_k^T\textbf{x}_k \\ 
  &s.t. \textbf{A}_i\textbf{x}_i \le \textbf{b}_i
 \end{split},\ \ (1)
\end{equation}
where $\textbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n,\textbf{Q}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is diagonal and positive definite matrix, $\textbf{A}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is sparse matrix.

Problem (1) can be also rewritten as follows:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  &\mathop{min} \limits_{\textbf{x}_1...\textbf{x}_k} \  \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{x}_1^T ... \textbf{x}_k^T\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{Q}_1 &  &  \\ & ...  & \\ & &  \textbf{Q}_k \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{x}_1\\ ...\\ \textbf{x}_k\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{q}_1^T ... \textbf{q}_k^T\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{x}_1\\ ...\\ \textbf{x}_k\end{bmatrix}\\ 
  &s.t. \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{A}_1 &  &  \\ & ...  & \\ & &  \textbf{A}_k \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{x}_1\\ ...\\ \textbf{x}_k\end{bmatrix} \le \begin{bmatrix} \textbf{b}_1\\ ...\\ \textbf{b}_k\end{bmatrix}
 \end{split}.\ \ (2)
\end{equation}

Since matrices in problem (2) are too large, and saving them usually leads to problem of out of memory, then I tend to solve k sub-problems as follows:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  &\mathop{min} \limits_{\textbf{x}_i} \  \frac{1}{2}\textbf{x}_i^T\textbf{Q}_i\textbf{x}_i+\textbf{q}_i^T\textbf{x}_i \\ 
  &s.t. \textbf{A}_i\textbf{x}_i \le \textbf{b}_i
 \end{split},\ \ (3)
\end{equation}
problem (3) can be solved by Augmented Lagrangian Method, whose algorithm can be roughly described as repreating the following three steps until convergence.

1.$\textbf{x}_i^{k+1}=\mathop{argmin} \limits_{\textbf{x}_i} \  L_{C_i}(\textbf{x}_i, \lambda_i)$
2.update $\lambda_i$
3.update $C_i$

However, for each sub-problem, if newton method is applied in step1 ($\textbf{x}_i^{k+1}=\mathop{argmin} \limits_{\textbf{x}_i} \  L_{C_i}(\textbf{x}_i, \lambda_i)$), in each iteration, it takes $O(n^3)$ to calculate the inverse of $L_c$'s Hessian matrix ($\textbf{Q}_i+C_i\textbf{A}_i^T\textbf{D}_i\textbf{A}_i$, where $\textbf{D}_i$ is a diagonal matrix). Therefore, solving problem (1) is very time consuming.

I guess problem (1) is frequently seen, and is there a faster way to solve it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have some structure (such as sparsity), most methods active set or interior will have a step using $n^3$ flops.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for replying me. Actually problem (1) can be rewritten as problem (2), and in problem (2), the big matrix A and Q are block-diagonal and diagonal, respectively. So is there a faster way for this special structure? Can you give me some key words?

Comment: Well, I found the time complexity of quasi-newton method is O(n^2), then problem can be solved faster.

Comment: I would find it hard to believe that there is an $O(n^2)$ solver for a QP when solving $Ax=b$ is usually $O(n^3)$.

Comment: @copper.hat The most time-consuming part is step1, which is an unconstrained convex optimization problem. If newton-raphson method is applied to solve step1, the time complexity is $O(n^3)$, because an inverse need to be calculated. However, quasi-newton method calculates an approximated inverse matrix instead. And the time complexity of calculating this approximated inverse matrix is $O(n^2)$.